# Getx theme management

Tags: flutter, themes, storage, flutter-getx

I am trying to implement theme management in my app.

In the GetMaterialApp I have:

```
themeMode:  ThemeService().getThemeMode(),
```

In the ThemeService class I have:

```
  ThemeMode getThemeMode() {
    String theme = getSavedTheme();
    print('Loading theme: $theme');

    switch (theme) {
      case 'dark':
        return ThemeMode.dark;
      case 'system':
        return ThemeMode.system;
      default:
        return ThemeMode.light;
    }
  }

  String getSavedTheme() {
    var value = _getStorage.read(storageKey);
    print('Loaded: $value');
    return value ?? 'light';
  }
```

When I open the app for the first time, the app always loads in light theme and I get the following output in the console:

```
I/flutter ( 4252): Loaded: null
I/flutter ( 4252): Loading theme: light
```

Seems like Getx Storage isn't loading the value from the stored prefs. Checking the file manually, the value is correct in the prefs:

```
{"savedTheme":"system"}
```

If I hot restart right after loading the app for the first time, it works properly and changes the app theme.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

Please check GetStorage initialization in Main method

```
void main() async { // make it async
  await GetStorage.init(); // add this
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have that. In fact, it works but not in the initial launch.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to replace

```
await GetStorage.init();
```

with

```
await GetStorage.init('theme');
```

For completness sake, this is what I had in the ThemeService class

```
class ThemeService {
  final _getStorage = GetStorage('theme');
  final themeBrightness = 'savedTheme';
  final themeColor = 'themeColor';

  ThemeMode getThemeMode() {
    String theme = getSavedTheme();
    print('Loading theme: $theme');

    switch (theme) {
      case 'dark':
        return ThemeMode.dark;
      case 'system':
        return ThemeMode.system;
      default:
        return ThemeMode.light;
    }
  }

  String getSavedTheme() {
    var value = _getStorage.read(themeBrightness);
    print('Loaded: $value');
    return value ?? 'light';
  }
}
```